# How do I buy Bitcoin with cash?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins, trade, cash

How do I buy Bitcoin with cash? I am Canadian, and have a lot of cash that I would like to convert to Bitcoin without using any banks. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes surely you can, Check out this website : https://localbitcoins.com/country/CA

Answer (score 0):

In the most basic sense you can do this. One way is to find some one who owns Bitcoins and will sell them to you. Give them cash and have them send their Bitcoin to your wallet. You can even verify that you have received the btc.

Comment: Also there are full time exchanges many listed innthe above link from Adam.   These often require id proof

Answer (score 0):

https://coinatmradar.com/ lists many ATM's, simply searching on Google for "Bitcoin ATM" gives you a map with locations, although you may get a lot of non bitcoin ATM's on there.

Answer (score 0):

check localbitcoins for help, or some other sites like bitcoinworld/paxful/or the bitcointalk forum. But you need to pay some commision on it, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

I knew about One Popular way to buy Bitcoin with cash that is Localbitcoins, there has a payment method to buy Bitcoin with cash.

Comment: I'm sure that is not the *only* way, but it is certainly a popular way...